# What was the Nietzsche's argument against theory of evolution?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-mind, nietzsche, nihilism, evolution

I had read about it a decade ago, but it looks like now I have forgotten his point. Can I know what was his argument against Darwin?

Comment: Found this as well as many other links in response to the google query, "Nietzsche criticism of Darwin." https://digitalcommons.lsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1018&context=prs_pubs

Answer (score 3):

Nietzsche apparently believed that evolution by natural selection accounted for species diversity, but he also believed that the quality of various lifeforms was differentiated by the degree to which they possess a 'vitalistic force'.

He maintained that life was not only impelled by a struggle for survival, but by a drive towards 'ever-greater complexity, diversity, multiplicity and creativity'.

Reference: https://philosophynow.org/issues/29/Nietzsche_and_Evolution

Comment: I think you make an accurate, concise statement of Nietzsche's dissatisfaction with Darwin. One upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer only a derivative response.

On a side note:

**How much did Nietzsche know?**

> Nietzsche, all agree, is unlikely to have read either  Darwin’s  The Origin of Species  (1859) or his  Descent of Man  (1871).  However, he had a basic if not entirely  accurate  grasp  of  Darwinism  derived  from  popularizers  and  synthesizers, and his direct engagement with the evolutionary theory of [Herbert] Spencer, in the latter’s three-volume  System of Synthetic Philosophy  (1862–67), is evident.  He mentions  Darwin,  Darwinism, and  Darwinians in works ranging from his early  Untimely Meditations  (1873) on the rationalist critic of Christianity,  David  Strauss,  to the notes  of the late  1880s  that were  assembled into a book by his sister and later published under the title  Der Wille zur Macht. (Catherine Wilson, 'Darwin and Nietzsche: Selection, Evolution, and Morality', Journal of Nietzsche Studies,  Vol. 44, No. 2 (Summer 2013), pp. 354-370: 355.)

**The clash of viewpoints**

> To summarize,  Nietzsche  was  engaged  in  a three-cornered  argument.  In  one corner stood the traditional Christians with their commitment to the repression of sensuality as evil and sin, and their supernaturalism.  In another corner were the agnostic or atheistic philosophers who wanted to assert, preserve, and even extend  Christian values in the face of science, including Kant,  Schopenhauer, Darwin,  Strauss, and  Spencer. In the third corner, there was  Nietzsche himself, aesthetically repelled by the masses and their unhealthy propensities, distressed by the suffering of superior  individuals, and hostile to traces  of asceticism and Orientalism  in  his  contemporaries.

> **In some respects, then, Nietzsche is a Darwinian. He believes that the history of humanity is part of natural history and that there is no sacred history as opposed to a history of sacerdotalism, and he believes (except in his idealist moments) that mental powers supervene on physical organization. Like Darwin, he believes that  individuals  vary  in  their  intrinsic  quality: some  are  superior  to  others.** He is also much closer to the view of the modern, neo-Darwinian biologist than were the nineteenth-century  Darwinians. It is the individual that matters to itself, regardless of the fate of the “species” to which it belongs. But **he rejects the basic Darwinian picture, according to which all differences between members of the  same  species  are  necessarily  minute  and  often  invisible  and  at  the same time cumulatively significant in the production of new “races” and ultimately, new species. He rejects as well the Darwinian postulate that altruism and self-abnegation are human traits acquired in the course of evolution and further refined in the highest forms of civilization, identifying instead an unnatural and sinister  origin  for  them  in  archaic  resentment** [*ressentiment*: GT]. (Wilson: 366-7.)

It doesn't affect the substance of her statement of Nietzsche's views about Darwin but the blithe reference to 'the agnostic or atheistic philosophers who wanted to assert, preserve, and even extend Christian values in the face of science, including Kant, Schopenhauer, Darwin, Strauss, and Spencer' lacks historical nuance.